# Add fitted (gamma) distribution density curve to histogram plot from library(MASS) fitdistr

Tags: r, plot, gamma-distribution

I would like to plot the gamma density function derived from a set of observations over the histogram of the observed data. I am able to generate the histogram and parameter estimates for the gamma fit. This is being done for multiple subsets of data from a master data set. How can I plot the gamma density function on each of the histograms created in this loop?

I currently have:

```
library(MASS)

species <- c('acesac', 'acesac', 'acesac', 'acesac', 'acesac', 'acesac',
 'polbif', 'polbif', 'polbif', 'polbif', 'polbif', 'polbif')
tmean <- c(2,3,5,6,6,7,5,6,6,6,8,9) 
Data <- data.frame(species, tmean) 

for (i in unique(Data$species)){
  subdata <- subset(Data, species ==i)
  hist(subdata$tmean, main = i)
  dist <- fitdistr(subdata$tmean, "gamma")
}
```

I'm thinking that I should use `lines()`, however, not sure how to specify this?

Comment: What is `Data`? Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: My apologies for not being able to provide a reproducible example. `Data` is the full dataset I am working with. The vector `subdata$tmean` is a set of temperature values in degrees C.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) about supplying a reproducible example. You can always use `dput()`.

Comment: [There are many ways to provide a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061). Give it a go. It **shouldn't** be your full data, it should be a small, representation that illustrates the problem, based on a subset of real data or on simulated data.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try...

Comment: I added an example for `Data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add `library(MASS)` to your example. You may want to try doing something with `curve` and using `add = TRUE`. Another option would be to use the `library(fitdistrplus)` as it can plot the output of `dist` directly; however, I could not find a way (quickly) to change the plot titles.

```
library(MASS)
species <- c('acesac', 'acesac', 'acesac', 'acesac', 'acesac', 'acesac',
             'polbif', 'polbif', 'polbif', 'polbif', 'polbif', 'polbif')
tmean <- c(2,3,5,6,6,7,5,6,6,6,8,9) 
Data <- data.frame(species, tmean) 

for (i in unique(Data$species)) {
  subdata <- subset(Data, species ==i)
  dist <- fitdistr(subdata$tmean, "gamma")
  hist(subdata$tmean, main = i)
  curve(dgamma(x, shape = dist$estimate[1], rate = dist$estimate[2]), 
        add = TRUE,
        col = "red")
}
```

Per my comment about `library(fitdistrplus)` see the output from:

```
library(fitdistrplus)

for (i in unique(Data$species)) {
  subdata <- subset(Data, species ==i)
  dist <- fitdistrplus::fitdist(subdata$tmean, "gamma")
  plot(dist)
}
```

Notice that you get additional graphs (Q-Q plot, empirical and theoretical CFS, and P-P plot) and the density lines are plotted for "free". However, you lose the ability to add `main = i`. I'm sure someone smarter than me can figure out a quick way to add titles or modify the `fitdistrplus::plot.fitdist` method - might be worth asking a separate question.

Comment: I added this line for `curve` (MASS was already loaded) and receive no errors, but it does not show the curve?

Comment: @user3830407 I meant adding `library(MASS)` to your original question so that it is fully reproducible. Are you sure the curve is not plotting? Try copying and pasting the exact code above.

Comment: The curve plots fine using the example dataset, however, it does not plot when using the actual `Data` (I'll have to check my data).  ...I was able to get the very nice set of plots using fitdistrplus! Many thanks for both solutions.

Comment: @user3830407 - perhaps the actual data does not follow a gamma distribution. best of luck and feel free to ask more reproducible questions.